# How to restart tasklet at specific interval

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

I have spring batch job as follows:

```
   <job id="messageConsumerJob"  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <split id="split1" task-executor="taskExecutor">
        <flow>
            <batch:step id="messageConsumerStep">
                <batch:partition step="receiverStep" partitioner="messageConsumer">
                    <batch:handler grid-size="10" task-executor="taskExecutor" />
                </batch:partition>
            </batch:step>   
        </flow>
        <flow>
            <step id="publishStep">
                <tasklet ref="messagePublish" />
            </step>
        </flow>
    </split>
</job>
```

I want to restart the receiver step every 2 days.

Comment: I want to run following method everytime.public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution arg0, ChunkContext arg1)

Comment: can you use TaskScheduler  to run that method periodically